# AWS S3 Transfer from Python Script on Apache

Tags: python, apache, amazon-s3

I have a use case where the user uploads a zip file to the server, the contents is processed, and then individual components are encrypted and sent to S3 using `boto3`.

Right now, all this happens in a single HTTPS PUT request to a python script on the apache server. Is there a canonical way to process transfers asynchronously so that users don't have to wait for all the processing?

The data itself is 200-800MB so passing the data around could take a moment and its unclear whether a queue should be created for post processing with a job scheduler running on the server to kickoff when an empty queue becomes full. The issue is that race conditions, running to completion, potential feedback on progress, etc might be required and a standard solution would be desirable here.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a Lambda Function triggered asynchronously.

The Lambda instance scales and already comes with the boto3 library installed to load your file on S3. If needed, you can easily add a preprocessing step directly inside the Lambda Function.

Here a full example of an async invocation in Python:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    'lambda',
    region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='your_key',
    aws_secret_access_key='your_secret',
)

payload = {"id": "123abc", "code": "8033712044378", "price": "11.11"}
payloadStr = json.dumps(payload)
payloadBytesArr = bytes(payloadStr, encoding='utf8')
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='your_lambda_function_name',
    InvocationType="Event",  # Event = Invoke the function asynchronously.
    Payload=payloadBytesArr
)
```

And [here the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) from AWS.

Comment: Can you explain what your lambda function is doing here?

Comment: In this case the script is sending some json encoded data asynchronously to a Lambda Function. Can you give more details about the data you need to send to S3 asynchronously? Are they greater than the input event limit? (it should be 128 K for asynchronous invocations)

Comment: In this case the data is 200-800MB so it seems undesirable to transfer to the lambda and have the lambda transfer to s3 when I could spend the time I would spend spend transferring to lambda actually transferring to s3 itself.  I think the link between the apache requests and a separate scheduled task is of great interest, though.